# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap in Asp.net MVC4 project(vs2010)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2UQqMU27BA&feature=youtu.be) very simple tutorial to create 
 MVC4 Project. But it kept giving me an error like this:
`The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context.  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")` 
what should I do ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MVC 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

As Sherbrow mentioned check you have MVC4 and the latest version installed. As I think the beta had a different syntax for both bundles than both the RC and the RTM version. open up your nuget package configuration and ensure the project is indeed referencing The RTM files.

Answer (score 0):

MVC4 actually doesn't provide this by default if you used the empty project template. You need to get a NuGet package and add a namespace for your Razor views:

1. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`
2. Open ~\Views\Web.config
3. Add an `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />` under `configuration/system.web.webPages.razor/pages/namespaces`
4. Rebuild & run. It should work.

It has nothing to do with Twitter.Bootstrap except that Twitter.Bootstrap suggests that you use an Empty project template